# Finding specific database entries when using nested attributes in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I'm using nested attributes in my Ruby on Rails app (4.0.2) such that survey has_many questions and accepts_nested_attributes_for questions and question belongs_to survey.

The problem that I have run into is that when I only want to look at the questions that belong to a particular survey I get an "undefined method "id" for nil:NilClass"-error. When on the other hand I look at all the questions the index action works without problems.

My questions controller index action:

```
  def index
     @questions = Question.where(:survey_id => @survey.id).all # if instead I use @questions = Question.all it works fine, but is not what I want.
     #@questions = @survey.questions.all
     @surveys = Survey.all
     @survey = Survey.first
 end
```

My surveys/index.html.erb page:

```
  <%= link_to("questions", { :controller => 'questions', :survey_id => survey.id }, :class => 'btn btn-xs') do %>
        <%= glyph 'th-list' %>
  <%- end -%>
```

My Question model:

```
 class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :survey
   scope :sorted, lambda { order("questions.created_at ASC")}
 end
```

I also use a before_action that I call find_survey which looks like this:

```
def find_survey
  # If in each action calling this method (find_survey) has :survey_id sent
  if params[:survey_id]
    # We will then go to the database and look for (and find) :survey_id and set that to @survey. 
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  end
end
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: @suslov Yes it does. My survey controller code: class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
 
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions , :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }

 scope :sorted, lambda { order("questions.created_at DESC")}

Comment: Perhaps returning questions for a given survey should be the responsibility of the Survey class, then you simply call `self.questions` from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined method on `NilClass` is because your instance variable `@survey` is nil, and when you're calling `Question.where(:survey_id => @survey.id).all` you're getting that error.

If you're associations are set up right you should be able to run `@survey.questions` and not have to perform the search on `Questions`. That's part of ActiveRecord rails magic. You SHOULDN'T have to call `@survey.questions.all` because that will return all intances of the Question class, leave that off and you should be good to go.

As far as why this isn't working for you now, it may just be an order thing — you're calling `@survey` before you define it on the line below.

Comment: I cannot believe it. The order in the controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you posted, `@survey` is likely `nil` in this line:

```
@questions = Question.where(:survey_id => @survey.id).all
```

So maybe your "before_action" is not being called?